# Reversing a String using a Stack (C++/CLI Visual Studio 2010 )

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I'm trying to reverse a String and display it in a Message Box in visual studio 2010 (C++). The problem is that the output contains the reversed string with some more characters.

When I try to reverse "Hello" the output should be "olleH" but the output is "olleHBYrHello"

**Here is my stack class implementation**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "StackX.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

StackX::StackX(int size)
{
    maxSize = size;
    top = -1;
    stackArray = new char[maxSize];
}
bool StackX::isFull()
{
    if(top == maxSize - 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
bool StackX::isEmpty()
{
    if(top == -1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
void StackX::push(char c)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Stack is full");
    }
    else
    {
        stackArray[++top] = c;

    }
}
char StackX::pop()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Stack is empty");
        return -99;
    }
    else
    {
        return stackArray[top--];
    }
}
```

**Here is the main code (written for a button click event)**

```
char text[] = "Hello";
char reverse[5];
StackX s(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    s.push(text[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    reverse[i] = s.pop();
}

String^ str = gcnew String(reverse);
MessageBox::Show(str);
```

**Headers included in main**

```
#pragma once
#include "StackX.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
```

Comment: provide MCVE on console example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a null at the end of the string.
C/C++ are null terminated strings, so if you don't terminate it with a null, the messagebox will just show all the characters in memory until it reaches a null value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    reverse[i] = s.pop();
}
reverse[5] = NULL;
```

Comment: How did you access "i" after the for loop?

Comment: @Studentofeverything right, well either move the declaration of i outside of the loop, or just write to position 5 (after the rest of the text)

Comment: It's definitely safer to move the declaration of i outside of the loop, in case string size is changed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a EOS character (`\0`) at the end of your `char*` to makr the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add '\0' to the `reverse` string to mark its end. Otherwise it will output/copy all the characters from `reverse` until it finds '\0'.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    reverse[i] = s.pop();
}

reverse[i] = '\0';
```

Reconsider also changing this

```
char reverse[5];
```

To this

```
char reverse[sizeof(text)];
```

Othervise you are going to get undefind behavior if you write outside `reserve` range.

Comment: How can "i" be accessed after the for loop like you have done above?